# Basis of Russell-Saunders (LS) coupling

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics

Which physical effects are accounted for in this model? I know its results include the effect of spin-spin coupling and orbit orbit coupling. Does it neglect spin-orbit coupling completely because it's much smaller than the other things accounted for?

Other interactions it might take into account include: electrostatic repulsion between electrons using the central field approximation or otherwise, residual non-central electrostatic repulsion, spin symmetry, attraction between the nucleus and electrons, relativistic corrections to kinetic energy, screening effects although that might come under Coulomb repulsion... I could go on. Are any of these part of the model?

I can't find where this coupling scheme comes from so I can't determine its assumptions. In particular, what is the relative importance of each interaction the model includes? So which has the smallest effect all the way up to which has the largest?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: @CountTo10 Not at all, direction on improving a question is always welcome. However the problem is not that I'm having trouble understanding something I've read (I've read both those webpages), it's that nothing I've read addresses my primary question: namely, what are the physical interactions this model accounts for? In order of their importance? And then I've listed some of the physical effects I think this theory might encompass. All the small adjustments that need making for higher accuracy.

Comment: @CountTo10 Based on your comments I have changed the phrasing of the question and hopefully improved it.